# How to put a v-card in the center of the page with Vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js

My goal is to have a v-card in the center of the page. I am using Vuetify. This code should work, but is doesn't:

```
<template>
  <v-container fill-height>
    <v-row align="center" justify="center">
      <v-col>
        <v-card flat color="grey" class="lighten-3" max-width="500px">
          <v-card-title>{{ title }}</v-card-title>
          <v-card-text>
            <slot name="content"></slot>
          </v-card-text>
          <v-card-actions>
            <slot name="actions"></slot>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

A bit more context: I am using it as a BaseComponent in multiple places. Here is am example:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <BaseInfoMenu title="Title">
      <template slot="content">
        //content
      </template>
      <v-btn slot="actions">...</v-btn
  </div>
  //Some invisible divs 
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. 
The div around the BaseInfoMenu component was the problem. I removed it.
Also align="center" must go into the v-col or alternatively remove v-col.
The functioning code looks like this:

```
<template>
  <v-container fill-height>
    <v-row justify="center" align="center"> //No v-col
      <v-card flat color="grey" class="lighten-3" max-width="500px">
        <v-card-title>{{ title }}</v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>
          <slot name="content"></slot>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
          <slot name="actions"></slot>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

And the context would be

```
<template>
  <BaseInfoMenu title="Title"> //no div
    <template slot="content">
      //content
    </template>
    <v-btn slot="actions">...</v-btn
  //Some invisible divs 
</template>
```